# Install Flash Player on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: html, flash, firefox, ubuntu

I have tried to install Flash Player over the "Ubuntu Software Center", but it won't work on Firefox. I had prevously installed Pepper Flash and now I have messed up with all. When I want to watch a video on Youtube, it appears "The plugin is disabled" and after a few seconds, the HTML5 Player loads and plays the video. All plugins are activated. On Facebook it won't even appear. It shows following: [image: Flash appears not installed]

I don't know how to proceed. It won't work on Facebook neither Chromium...
From time to time it shows a yellow square with a "X" in it with following message instead of this above: "Failed to load libpepflashplayer.so".
It's very annoying. How can I wipe all this players from my machine and begin from zero?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu 14.04 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: Did you install the 32bit Flash Player?

Comment: Idk.. I have only tried to install from the software center and from "apt-get", but I don't have noticed any "64" in these lines...

Comment: You have to install 64bit via apt-get, I'll post the steps to remove 32bit and install 64bit.

Comment: That will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### To Remove 32bit Flash Player on Ubuntu 14.04

**Step 1** » Open Ubuntu Software Center.

**Step 2** » Click the `Installed` button next to the `All Software` button.

**Step 3** » Find the Adobe Flash Player package.

> My installation was found under the `Uncategorized` section and has the name
>   `Adobe Flash Player plugin version xx`.

**Step 4** » Click the `Remove` button.

### To Install 64bit Flash Player on Ubuntu 14.04

**Step 1** » Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with a text editor (i.e. Vim, Gedit, etc.) Find and uncomment the below lines.

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

**Step 2** » Update the repository. (*Note: Don't type the `$`*)

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 3** » Install flash plugin using the below command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

**Step 4** » Test your installation.

> [Click this link](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) to test your installation.

**Source:** [How to Install Adobe Flash Player on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-adobe-flash-player-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. Use below commands to update your adobe flash player:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It will ask for your password.

```
sudo apt-get install -y flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: since firefox 36 (iirc) that is not enough, as youtube uses HTML5 player by default. solution: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/

Answer (score 0):

You may need `flashplugin-installer` and `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` or `adobe-flashplugin` depending on the browser you use.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html.en for a comprehensive answer.